# TensorFlow обучение на GPU

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

Как в TensorFlow обучать модели, используя GPU?
Данный код показывает, что GPU у меня 0, хотя видеокарта есть.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Только начал знакомиться с TensorFlow, поэтому сразу извиняюсь, если задаю глупый вопрос.

Comment: укажите операционную систему, название видеокарты. установлены ли видео-драйвера к видеокарте?

Comment: драйвера CUDA для Nvidia тут https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64         :) и надеюсь у вас не AMD GPU

Comment: @nexoma Спасибо!